Add multiple attributes in QGIS composer legend
I have a layer to make simple plans for planting forests. In this layer I have a field to indicate a zone for planting shrubs and a field to mark wich species should be planted there.
In the print composer I work with an atlas on a different layer to zoom at different locations. At each location the species variate.
Now I would like to get all the shrub species in the legend for each zone visible on the map. This would save me a lot of time, now I type in manually.
So I need some expression in the properties of the legend item, but I don't know how?
Is this possible to do in QGIS?
The image below can clarify my intentions. The species in the field "soorten bosrand" should come in the legend.

